# What is a faster way to display this additional data I have?

Tags: html, ajax, database

Let's say I have a page with 2 columns. The left column is a table of rows with data filled with (first name, middle name, last name) and the right column is going to display additional information (address, age, hair color, eye colors) when I click on one of the rows on the left column.

I tried ajax call, it take a few seconds to load the additional information on the right column. Is there a better approach to this to load the additional information on the right column faster or instantly?

Btw, these data are from the database.

[image: Example of what I'm trying to explain]

Comment: Are you using a .php script to data from the DB? If so, can you post that (redacting sensitive info) so we can see if it's an issue with your script?

Comment: Can you download all the data with the page, and then just set the right-hand table data when you click on the left?

Comment: @colonelsanders - I'm using $.ajax call to send to the php side and get a response back to the ajax call and just replace that <div> tag with the new data.

Comment: @dhc - Do you mean have all the data ready when the page loads and then just have those data hide and show?

Comment: yes, since all the data is available client-side anyway, I don't see a security risk here...